# Angular reactive form select default value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to make a crud. The issue is in the update form, I want to load the person object related to a promoter in the select option and I'm returning the value in a ternary condition.

Here is the html:

```
<select
  formControlName="person"
  id="person">
      <option
        *ngFor="let person of persons"
         [ngValue]="(promoter.person.id === person.id)? person : persons[0]">
           {{ person.name }}
      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you reproduce your issue on https://stackblitz.com/ pls ?

Comment: Choose **or** template driven forms (NgModel) **or** reactive forms (formControlName) but **not** use in the same tag ngModel and FormControlName. see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all who tried to help me, but I already solved my approach this way:

```
<select
  formControlName="person"
  id="person">
  <option
    *ngIf="promoter.id"
    [ngValue]="promoter.person">{{promoter.person.name}}</option>
      <option
        *ngFor="let person of persons"
        [ngValue]="person">
          {{ person.name }}
      </option>
</select>
```

I understand that maybe my question wasn't as clear as expected, thanks one more time.